# Grails - How to define the starting index page URL

Tags: grails, gsp

In grails, supposing you have a project named 'MainProject', my default index is `http://localhost:8080/MainProject/` and the page associated with this exact url is `views/index.gsp`.

I would like the starting link of the project NOT to be `http://localhost:8080/MainProject/` but something like `http://localhost:8080/MainProject/users/login`.

I tried to edit the URL Mappings from this:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view: '/index')
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

to this:

```
class UrlMappings {

    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }

        "/"(view: '/users/login')
        "500"(view:'/error')
    }
}
```

After the above change, by starting the project, the url remains as `http://localhost:8080/MainProject/`, but the page shown is not `views/index.gsp`
 but `views/users/login.gsp`. The gsp is correctly rendered, but the url is still not the one I need.

How to solve this?

Comment: I believe you would do this with:
`"/"(redirect: '/users/login')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with:

```
"/"(redirect: '/users/login')
```

Also see [Grails URL Mapping Documentation](https://docs.grails.org/2.5.0/guide/single.html#urlmappings)